# NetLogo - Delaying the execution of certain commands based on ticks

Tags: list, foreach, simulation, netlogo, nested-loops

Hello NetLogo community,

I am trying to ask agents named "users" to save certain value (string) of a variable for last two ticks (last two instances when "Go" command is executed). But, users have to store these values after first two ticks. Can anyone suggest me a way out? I have tried implementing the following logic but it does not seem to work.

```
ask users
  [
    set history-length-TM 2
    if ticks > 2
    [
      set TM-history n-values history-length-TM [mode-taken]
      foreach TM-history [x = "car"]
      [
        commands that are to be executed
        .....
        ......
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

"history-length-TM" is the extent of ticks for which the values are to be stored. "TM-History" is the list to store the values of variable "mode-taken". Please advise a better method that could help me achieve the intent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand how ticks relates to this question. My suggestion would be something along these lines:

```
globals [history-length-TM]
users-own [TM-history]

to setup
  set history-length-TM 2
  ...
end

ask users
  ....
  set TM-history fput mode-taken TM-history
  if length [TM-history] > history-length-TM [set TM-history but-last TM-history]
end
```

The idea is that the memory fills up (using `fput`) by placing the new mode-taken at the front of the list. Once the memory is too long, then the last (which is oldest) is dropped off the list.

Comment: Hello Mr/Ms Jen B, Thanks for your feedback. I realize your code is helpful to store mode-taken values in a list of TM-history for a specified length with latest being the "item 0" in the list and the previous value being the "item 1" in the list and subsequently updating. However, I want to do agents to perform such commands not from the first tick but after couple of ticks as there will already be 2 values for mode-taken by the third tick and this is to be done by purpose for the need of the program. Could you recommend an alternative if possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Mr./Ms. JenB, "already 2 values" is the result of storing the values of "mode-taken" as in my code: "set TM-history n-values history-length-TM [mode-taken]". I want this to happen from the third tick is all I need to understand. Thank you for taking time out to answer my question.

Comment: Any code inside `if ticks > 2 [ ...... ]` will occur from tick number 3 and later